# RealSense error calling rs_create_context(api_version:4)

Tags: ubuntu, intel, realsense

I've just acquired Realsense Robotic Development Kit, and while installing it following the guide given by intel: https://01.org/developerjourney/recipe/intel-realsense-robotic-development-kit#comments, I ended up getting this error whenever I tried to recieve image from the camera.

Since I have the correct kernel on the upboard, I think that it must be a problem in either the realsense or the udev rules installation.

Does anyone found this error and knows how to come through it?

Answer (score 0):

> Check that your librealsense* is installed correctly. 
>   I guess that it should be properly installed "out of the box" but you can still verify that you have all the required components [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/installation.md)

*librealsense is a library for capturing data from the Intel RealSense cameras. And the rs_create_context is a method of that library.

By the way, if you wrote your own application then consider using rs::context as can be found in the [examples](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/examples)

Otherwise (you use sample application) everything should work fine.